# Manually skip job in github

Tags: deployment, build, github-actions

We are managing to change our CI/CD process on github. Previously we were using one branch by environment (Test and Production).
Now, we would like to have the same build deployed on all environment. So we are using one main branch which build and allow to deploy on Test environement and if it succeed and approved to prodution.
So far so good.
Most of the time, we are deploying in Test environment only. For this cases, we are rejecting or cancelling the workflow after deploying to Test but our actions and Pull request are all in failled state.
The question is, how could we manually skipped the production deployment without having the status of Github action being failed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are different options (so the answers will be opinion based). I would probably divide the workflow in 2 workflows (or a reusable one with a workflow_dispatch trigger along with the workflow_call trigger), sending a dispatch event to the workflow deploying in Production from the Test workflow. The manual approval would still stand in the Production workflow in that case, and if canceled, the Test workflow would still appear as success as there would be different workflow runs for each environment.

Comment: Hi Gui, Thanks for your answer but sending event to another workflow make itself to build the solution again and we would like to have the same build for all and we do not have an artifactory tool for the moment